# Xcode 7 created new branch, commit fails

Tags: ios, github, version-control, xcode7

Recently upgraded to Xcode 7 with an in progress app. Got app running fine but when I went to commit first changes in Xcode 7, I got the below error:

**The working copy “App Name” failed to commit files.**
error: invalid object 100644 07ce6672fd469d5c7545e48b910cb3ff4508e9ca for 'App Name/App Name-Prefix.pch'
error: invalid object 100644 07ce6672fd469d5c7545e48b910cb3ff4508e9ca for 'App Name/App Name-Prefix.pch'
error: Error building trees

I then noticed that I now have an additional branch under Source Control in Xcode...one that says "Project Name - master" and one with just the Project name (no master). Previously, I only worked on a master branch since I'm working by myself. Does anyone know why this happened after upgrading to XCode 7? I've upgraded Xcode versions before with existing projects and never had this happen. More importantly, how do I resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying multiple solutions to this from other threads with no success, I was able to solve this with a very simple solution...deleted the xcode project locally and cloned the most recent git repository, then opened the project again in XCode. I dragged my unsaved changed files to the desktop first and then replaced them after cloning and all was well again. This solution may not work for everyone depending on the scenario, but it worked well enough for me.

Comment: this helped me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use terminal to commit:

```
git init
git add -a
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/truhoada/StackoverFlow.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what exactly is this doing? Will I lose all of the previous history of the master branch? Will I still be able to see the differences of current changes when I go to check them in?

Comment: This didn't work. Got the error complaining about the prefix.pch file after the commit -m line...

error: invalid object 100644 07ce6672fd469d5c7545e48b910cb3ff4508e9ca for 'CollectionView-POC/CollectionView-POC-Prefix.pch'
error: Error building trees

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete your project. The problem is git is corrupted.

**Here's how I fixed it without deleting and reconstructing the project.**
[image: error message example]

1. **Make a backup copy of your project.** Copy the top-most folder that contains your project and all its assets to another folder.
2. **Find the last commit that worked.** Drop to terminal in the original folder, then use `git log` to get the list of commits. The current commit is garbage so look for the last prior commit (that will generally be the next commit listed. Highlight and copy the last working commit hash using cmd+C.
   [image]

```bash
> git log
commit 771e79597dd0b6b6cd4147c3a471878fda3cd0e4 (HEAD -> fixgit)
```

3. **Hard reset to last working commit.** This is going to destroy any work you have not staged, so make sure you have made the backup copy in step 1. *Consider doing a time machine backup before you try this if you are afraid you'll lose your work.*

```bash
> git reset --hard 771e795
HEAD is now at 771e795 - fix play speed variability
```

*Replace `771e795` with YOUR commit hash.*

4. **Copy your changes back, less the '.git' folder.** Select your project files/folders from the backup you made in step 1 back into the original folder that you just hard reset. ***DO NOT copy the .git folder else you'll have to do the hard reset all over again, or worse, have to start over from the time machine backup recommended in step 3.***
5. **Stage your changes and commit**.