# Cannot resolve Git/Xcode 7 repository issue - commit fails, error building trees

Tags: ios, github, version-control, xcode7

I recently posting another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053917/xcode-7-created-new-branch-commit-fails) for this issue, but was not able to resolve it from the responses posted. In short, upgraded to XCode 7 and somehow a new branch was created...had previously only worked on the master branch. During my first commit on XC7, I got the error that the commit failed due to failing to build trees (full error provided in above link). I've tried a few things, including what was suggested in the response to my previous thread, but it did not work. I've also tried going into XC and clicking on Source Control->App Name->master->Switch to Branch and then selecting the master branch thinking this would get me back to master branch. When doing that I got an error: Failed to write reference 'refs/heads/master': a reference with that name already exists. (-4).

I am completely stuck and really need to get past this. Can someone please help provide an alternate solution? Can I just download the current code from git and start a new XCode project? I'm using cocoa pods so I launch the project from the projectname.xcworkspace file...would it cause issues if I tried starting a new porject? I've made a few code changes that I was trying to check in when I discovered the issue but I've copied them to my desktop and could replace them once I get the source control issue resolved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error
"Failed to write reference 'refs/heads/master': a reference with that name already exists. (-4)."
Can occur if you try switching from a local branch to the remote 'master' branch. Ensure that the 'master' you are switching to is the local one.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this question. You must 'push' your changes to the remote 'master'. You cannot switch from a 'local' master to the 'remote 'master, instead you *push* local changes in the local master to the remote master.