# My xcode is showing two branches open at same time in source control

Tags: ios, xcode, git, xcode7

My xcode is showing two branches open at same time in source control. i want to remove one brance from that. because it was producing some uncommited changes when i switch branch. Screenshot is attached. Thanks for your help in advance. 
Additional details Xcoed Version : 7.1[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_control_management/MergingTwoBranches/MergingTwoBranches.html

Comment: Hi anil, I am not asking about "how to merge two branch?". My Project showing two branches are opened at same time. Actually only one branch should show in source control Menu. but in my project it shows 2 branches. i need solution for How to close/remove any one of branch from source control Menu not from git. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried checking out what is going on in the git repo via the command line? Just navigate to the repo location and run `git status`

Comment: yes this only shows single branch details @luk2302 the details added above.

Comment: have you tried just quitting xcode and restarting it, maybe it just got a hiccup.

Comment: yes @luk2302 but still its there. restarted my mac too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053917/xcode-7-created-new-branch-commit-fails?rq=1 this link helped me to resolve this issue. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and found out how to remove the undesired branch under this environment : XCODE 7.3 (7D175) and use of CocoaPods generating '.xcworkspace' file.

Following the steps hereafter is the way to find and remove the branch :
1. Locate the 'MyApplication.xcworkspace' file.
2. Open this file with TextWrangler for instance (the following steps must be done in the chosen editor).
3. You should see two folders : 'xcshareddata' and 'xcuserdata'. Unfold  'xcshareddata'.
4. Select and open the 'MyApplication.xcsmblueprint' file.

Now, you should see some lines where the branch you want to remove is written.
Note its ID in the 'DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintIdentifierKey' section and then select all the lines where it appears so as to delete them at the same time.
These lines are located in kind of dictionaries.

Open your project in XCODE and you shouldn't see your undesired branch anymore in the 'Source Control' menu.

## Added Explanation

@Muthu Selvam :

1. In your '.xcscmblueprint' file, take a look at the titled dictionary "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyPathsKey" (line 12). You notice you have 3 Ids as keys and names as values.
   Here, it means you have 3 different branches apparently and two of them having the same name (weird ???).
2. Now, if you take a look at the titled array of dictionaries "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoriesKey" (line 20), each of your 3 branches is deeply described in a dedicated dictionary.
   That's here you see the one you want to keep and those you have to remove (look at the "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoryURLKey" in each dictionary).
3. Once you have selected the IDs of the 2 branches you want to delete, take a look at the titled dictionary "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyStatesKey" (line 6) and remove the 2 undesired lines including the 2 undesired IDs.
4. Same as step 3 in the titled dictionary "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyPathsKey" (line 12).
5. Last but not least, remove the entire 2 dictionaries in the titled array "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoriesKey" (line 20).

It should work.  :o)

Comment: Thanks @XLE_22, I have tried your approach. My MyApplication.xcsmblueprint content is available here (https://www.dropbox.com/s/1cgoym5ote4e0zu/CRM-Software-App.xcscmblueprint?dl=0). can you tell what should i remove on this. because i can't understand your third paragraph. can you help on this.

Comment: Thanks and great Work @XLE_22. its now solved the issue. once again thanks a lot for detailed explanation.