# Xcode delete working copies of source control

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, xcode7.3

I am trying to delete a working copy of my project, I came across this answer 
[Xcode Source Control showing multiple Working Copies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516220/xcode-source-control-showing-multiple-working-copies)

But seems that in Xcode 7.3.1 ( I don't know which version they change it) there is no file "xcshareddata" mentioned in the answer

So I don't know how to achieve it in my Xcode

Comment: Maybe this answer could help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389121/my-xcode-is-showing-two-branches-open-at-same-time-in-source-control/36694739#36694739

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First please select **shared** in manage scheme: set the active scheme (next to stop button) -> manage schemes -> click the scheme -> edit -> select shared in the bottom of the window

Then open the xcode project folder -> projectname.xcodeproj -> show Package Conents -> xcshareddata -> schemes -> edit and save file