# xcode 8 remove unused working copy under source control

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

I'm working with Xcode 8 and git as source control. I have made my one git for the project. How can we remove the unused working copy as bellow pic

[image]

I want to delete the "SAM" working copy to avoid confusion. How can we delete that.

### Updated

I have edit the xcscmblueprint file. but seem the unused still appear.

Here is my content of xcmblueprint file (after modified)

```
{
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintPrimaryRemoteRepositoryKey" : "1D213AF52C5E818A80BAB36B9C687DEB14CD1671",
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyRepositoryLocationsKey" : {

  },
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyStatesKey" : {
    "1D213AF52C5E818A80BAB36B9C687DEB14CD1671" : 9223372036854775807
  },
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintIdentifierKey" : "1A669691-0E1E-4D71-AD4F-5F0808376441",
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyPathsKey" : {
    "1D213AF52C5E818A80BAB36B9C687DEB14CD1671" : "eSAM\/"
  },
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintNameKey" : "SAMKiosk",
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintVersion" : 204,
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRelativePathToProjectKey" : "SAMKiosk.xcodeproj",
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoriesKey" : [
    {
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoryURLKey" : "https:\/\/github.com\/victory1908\/SingPostESam.git",
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositorySystemKey" : "com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git",
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoryIdentifierKey" : "1D213AF52C5E818A80BAB36B9C687DEB14CD1671"
    }
  ]
}
```

Hi updated my original xcmblueprint  (before modified)

```
{
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintPrimaryRemoteRepositoryKey" : "1D213AF52C5E818A80BAB36B9C687DEB14CD1671",
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyRepositoryLocationsKey" : {

  },
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyStatesKey" : {
    "CCEA429BB0CEB6873EA4927D131EA2335FDBC324" : 0,
    "1D213AF52C5E818A80BAB36B9C687DEB14CD1671" : 9223372036854775807
  },
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintIdentifierKey" : "1A669691-0E1E-4D71-AD4F-5F0808376441",
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyPathsKey" : {
    "CCEA429BB0CEB6873EA4927D131EA2335FDBC324" : "SAM",
    "1D213AF52C5E818A80BAB36B9C687DEB14CD1671" : "eSAM\/"
  },
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintNameKey" : "SAMKiosk",
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintVersion" : 204,
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRelativePathToProjectKey" : "SAMKiosk.xcodeproj",
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoriesKey" : [
    {
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoryURLKey" : "https:\/\/github.com\/victory1908\/SingPostESam.git",
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositorySystemKey" : "com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git",
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoryIdentifierKey" : "1D213AF52C5E818A80BAB36B9C687DEB14CD1671"
    },
    {
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoryURLKey" : "https:\/\/github.com\/ZNO-INTL\/SAM.git",
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositorySystemKey" : "com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git",
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoryIdentifierKey" : "CCEA429BB0CEB6873EA4927D131EA2335FDBC324"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [Xcode delete working copies of source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101383/xcode-delete-working-copies-of-source-control).

You must select **shared** for scheme first otherwise you will not find `.xcshareddata` file.

Please try to modify file as below, and then restart:

```
{
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintPrimaryRemoteRepositoryKey" : "1D213AF52C5E818A80BAB36B9C687DEB14CD1671",
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyRepositoryLocationsKey" : {

  },
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyStatesKey" : {
    "1D213AF52C5E818A80BAB36B9C687DEB14CD1671" : 9223372036854775807
  },
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintIdentifierKey" : "1A669691-0E1E-4D71-AD4F-5F0808376441",
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyPathsKey" : {
    "1D213AF52C5E818A80BAB36B9C687DEB14CD1671" : "eSAM\/"
  },
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintNameKey" : "SAMKiosk",
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintVersion" : 204,
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRelativePathToProjectKey" : "SAMKiosk.xcodeproj",
  "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoriesKey" : [
    {
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoryURLKey" : "https:\/\/github.com\/victory1908\/SingPostESam.git",
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositorySystemKey" : "com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git",
      "DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoryIdentifierKey" : "1D213AF52C5E818A80BAB36B9C687DEB14CD1671"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I have update the file but the unused working copy still appear. I updated the question with content of the file after edited

Comment: You need to update this four parameters (remove the repo about SAM and keep repo about eSAM): `DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyRepositoryLocationsKey`, `DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyStatesKey`, `DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyPathsKey ` and `DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoriesKey`.

Comment: Hi i have updated my original xcmblueprint file in the question. Make some modify in the edited file. Can me take a look what need to be changed? many thanks

Comment: Hi I update it in my answer, please have a try. please restart xcode. to check if works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Manage to delete the unused one. I have an outer folder name "SAM" move everything out out the folder and delete that folder solve the issue